# Foreach loop issue with multiple arrays

Tags: php, arrays

Let me explain my problem.
I have an array with dates and numbers in format ($cronograma)

Ex:

```
Array
(
    [2020-09-21] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2020-09-21
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 2
        )

    [2020-09-28] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2020-09-28
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 4
        )
```

Then i have another array with 2 ids (in this case 58,60) ($id)

Finally i have a third array with numbers only (in this case 34,34) $tot

So what i want is cross information beween them, for example
for id 58
I must get dates (first element and last element when $tot = 34)
for id 60
I must get dates (first element after $tot =34 and last element of array)

What I have so far is this

```
foreach ($id as $idPlan) {
        foreach ($cronograma as $c) {
            $t1 = 0;
            foreach ($tot as $d) {
                $t1 += (int)$d['tempos'];
                if ($c[3] == $t1) {
                    $newAr[] =$idPlan;
                    $newAr[] = $c[0];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Array contents:

```
array(8) { 
  [0]=> string(2) "58" 
  [1]=> string(10) "2021-02-01" 
  [2]=> string(2) "58"  
  [3]=> string(10) "2021-06-14"  
  [4]=> string(2) "60"  
  [5]=> string(10) "2021-02-01"  
  [6]=> string(2) "60"  
  [7]=> string(10) "2021-06-14" 
} null
```

So it's clear that i have all repeated

I should have a line like:

58 - 2020-09-21 -2021-02-01

Any help?

**UPDATE**

My **$cronograma array**

```
    2020-09-21 - 2 - 0 - 2
2020-09-22 - 2 - 0 - 2
2020-09-28 - 2 - 0 - 4
2020-09-29 - 2 - 0 - 4
2020-10-06 - 2 - 0 - 6
2020-10-12 - 2 - 0 - 6
2020-10-13 - 2 - 0 - 8
2020-10-19 - 2 - 0 - 8
2020-10-20 - 2 - 0 - 10
2020-10-26 - 2 - 0 - 10
2020-10-27 - 2 - 0 - 12
2020-11-02 - 2 - 0 - 12
2020-11-03 - 2 - 0 - 14
2020-11-09 - 2 - 0 - 14
2020-11-10 - 2 - 0 - 16
2020-11-16 - 2 - 0 - 16
2020-11-17 - 2 - 0 - 18
2020-11-23 - 2 - 0 - 18
2020-11-24 - 2 - 0 - 20
2020-11-30 - 2 - 0 - 20
2020-12-07 - 2 - 0 - 22
2020-12-14 - 2 - 0 - 24
2020-12-15 - 2 - 0 - 22
2021-01-04 - 2 - 0 - 26
2021-01-05 - 2 - 0 - 24
2021-01-11 - 2 - 0 - 28
2021-01-12 - 2 - 0 - 26
2021-01-18 - 2 - 0 - 30
2021-01-19 - 2 - 0 - 28
2021-01-25 - 2 - 0 - 32
2021-01-26 - 2 - 0 - 30
2021-02-01 - 2 - 0 - 34
2021-02-02 - 2 - 0 - 32
2021-02-08 - 2 - 0 - 36
2021-02-09 - 2 - 0 - 34
2021-02-22 - 2 - 0 - 38
2021-02-23 - 2 - 0 - 36
2021-03-01 - 2 - 0 - 40
2021-03-02 - 2 - 0 - 38
2021-03-08 - 2 - 0 - 42
2021-03-09 - 2 - 0 - 40
2021-03-15 - 2 - 0 - 44
2021-03-16 - 2 - 0 - 42
2021-03-22 - 2 - 0 - 46
2021-03-23 - 2 - 0 - 44
2021-04-05 - 2 - 0 - 48
2021-04-06 - 2 - 0 - 46
2021-04-12 - 2 - 0 - 50
2021-04-13 - 2 - 0 - 48
2021-04-19 - 2 - 0 - 52
2021-04-20 - 2 - 0 - 50
2021-04-26 - 2 - 0 - 54
2021-04-27 - 2 - 0 - 52
2021-05-03 - 2 - 0 - 56
2021-05-04 - 2 - 0 - 54
2021-05-10 - 2 - 0 - 58
2021-05-11 - 2 - 0 - 56
2021-05-17 - 2 - 0 - 60
2021-05-18 - 2 - 0 - 58
2021-05-24 - 2 - 0 - 62
2021-05-25 - 2 - 0 - 60
2021-05-31 - 2 - 0 - 64
2021-06-01 - 2 - 0 - 62
2021-06-07 - 2 - 0 - 66
2021-06-08 - 2 - 0 - 64
2021-06-14 - 2 - 0 - 68
2021-06-15 - 2 - 0 - 66
2021-06-22 - 2 - 0 - 68
```

The second array " ids" is 2 differents school subjects (ex: Mat and English)
**$id array**

The third array is related to hours of each school subjects (ex: Mat and English), in this case 34 hours each
**$tot array**

What i want is to slip this info by id array

So, since i have 2 ids (58, 60)

id        stardate          endDate            total

58     2020-09-21     2021-02-01        34

60    2021-02-08      2021-06-22        68

So i started to put foreach for array ids, inside foreach for array cronograma, and inside hours array

But the response given is not what i'm looking for

**UPDATE 2**

I need all since because this array is organized in 2 class groups, each group must have 68 hours.Since covid 19, a class can't have more than 15 students
In this case i must have 2 groups, thats why i have 2 different dates for 34 and 68 hours

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the logic. Try to explain it with another example.

Comment: can you include the arrays in the code (`$cronograma`, `$id`, `$tot`)? And what is `'tempos'`? you mentioned that $tot was an array with numbers only and then in the code you are referencing its elements using $d['tempos']...

Comment: You have multiple `34` (`2021-02-01 - 2 - 0 - 34` and `2021-02-09 - 2 - 0 - 34`) so which one do you pick? You picked the first, so how can you have `60 2021-02-08` when you need the _first element after $tot =34_ ?

Comment: Check Update 2, thanks